nvim : color of the lateral warning bar (EdenEast/nightfox)
If it matters, I am using the colorsheme EdenEast/nightfox with nvim : Plug 'EdenEast/nightfox.nvim' in init.vim.
I want to colorize the lateral when pyright detects an error.
More specifically, I am speaking of the vertical lateral bar in which pyright adds >> on the lines containing errors.
I want that bar to be fully colorized when there is an error anywhere in the file.


The secret is SignColumn.
Here is the portion of code (in init.vim) which changes the color of the sign column when an error is detected:
function! ShowDiagnostics()
    let diagnostics = CocAction('diagnosticList')
    if !empty(diagnostics)
        highlight SignColumn guibg=#00ff56
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePost *.py call ShowDiagnostics()


